# How to identify Azure AD cloud-based applications returned by Microsoft Graph API /beta/applications endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

I have a work account in Azure AD which has been granted with access for some cloud based applications within an organisation. I can login, see and start the applications from the [MyApps portal](https://myapps.microsoft.com).

I created a simple Javascript (React) application that needs to read the same list of applications. I'm fetching it from Microsoft Graph API /beta/applications endpoint.

How do I filter the list to keep only the cloud based apps shown in MyApps portal?

I successfully implemented the following:

- Authentication using MSAL against Azure AD.
- Fetched the list of all applications within user's organisation from Microsoft Graph API (GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications). I can see the same list in Azure Portal (Azure Active Directory -> App registrations (Preview)) for the specified organisation which is named here "directory".

This is an application item returned by Microsoft Graph API and shown in MyApps portal:

```
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-28a2179502fc",
  "deletedDateTime": null,
  "isFallbackPublicClient": false,
  "appId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-987d1f301c21",
  "identifierUris": [ "https://bitbucket.xxxxxxxxxx.io/plugins/servlet/samlsso", "http://samlssoforbitbucketbyresolutionXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXB9CCD803EA52CD5", "http://instanceid_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-19ba3d89b76f_XXXXXXXXXXXXX342A36A84E328233FB4", "http://samlssoforbitbucketbyresolution/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e3b08c22b8e9" ],
  "createdDateTime": "2017-12-02T09:05:35Z",
  "displayName": "Bitbucket",
  "isDeviceOnlyAuthSupported": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "orgRestrictions": [],
  "publisherDomain": null,
  "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
  "tags": [],
  "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
  "api": {
    "requestedAccessTokenVersion": null,
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
      {
        "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access SAML SSO for Bitbucket by resolution GmbH on behalf of the signed-in user.",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access SAML SSO for Bitbucket by resolution GmbH",
        "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f434ba7b017f",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access SAML SSO for Bitbucket by resolution GmbH on your behalf.",
        "userConsentDisplayName": "Access SAML SSO for Bitbucket by resolution GmbH",
        "value": "user_impersonation"
      }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": []
  },
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [ "User" ],
      "description": "msiam_access",
      "displayName": "msiam_access",
      "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2c6355321d55",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "origin": "Application",
      "value": null
    }
  ],
  "publicClient": { "redirectUris": [] },
  "info": {
    "termsOfServiceUrl": null,
    "supportUrl": null,
    "privacyStatementUrl": null,
    "marketingUrl": null,
    "logoUrl": "https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/c1c6b6c8-ugrfrtjv0so5ofkk2h6reh-pajssvvffd-ccwghwns/appbranding/ovibbplm5xqvqcq-zht1z7zxk3gr-vyq3raaci-yoj4/1033/bannerlogo?ts=636727159738380290"
  },
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
  },
  "passwordCredentials": [],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [],
  "web": {
    "redirectUris": [ "https://bitbucket.xxxxxxxxxx.io/plugins/servlet/samlsso", "https://*.lab.resolution.de/plugins/servlet/samlsso" ],
    "homePageUrl": "https://*.lab.resolution.de/plugins/servlet/samlsso?metadata=samlssoforbitbucketbyresolution|ISV9.2|primary|z",
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "implicitGrantSettings": {
      "enableIdTokenIssuance": true,
      "enableAccessTokenIssuance": false
    }
  }
}
```

I would have been expected a flag or type field but I couldn't find any to differentiate the items.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/active-directory-saas-access-panel-introduction) is documenting MyApps portal.

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/active-directory-saas-access-panel-introduction) is the documentation of the endpoint.

I will be grateful for any help to bring some light on this.

Comment: Cannot find a way to filter only cloud based apps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible right now using Microsoft Graph API beta.